# Are there a way to progress or age key pairs

Tags: keys, x25519

I am searching for a way to make the [noise X pattern](https://noiseexplorer.com/patterns/X/) fully forward secret. The X pattern is a way to encrypted and authenticated messages. As a building block to achieve this I started pondering if there is a way to progress a key pair ($a$, $A$). Use a one way function on $a$ to calculate $a'$ and another function on $A$ to calculate $A'$ while $A'$ is the public key to $a'$. This process could the be repeated.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    a @>>> a' @>>> a'' @>>> \\
    @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
    A @>>> A' @>>> A'' @>>>
\end{CD}
The idea is to house the progressing key pair in the receiving device and to burn old $a$:s at specific times. The sender could calculate the public key that is valid for a specific time (3 days from now) and then send.

Another way to achieve this would be to have a huge list of key pairs that expire at specific times. So this is a optimisation to get around using a huge list.

I am at this time more interested if this kind of functionality exist instead of if it is a good fit for my use case. Could it work with x25519 or ed25519? Could the function work so that $A$ could be progressed directly to $A''$ without calculating $A'$. Could it work some how with collective threshold decryption?

**Update**
Will not help in my case but just as an example. I believe that this kind of pattern could work. Probably broken for some reason...
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    a @>a^3 \: mod \: p>> a' @>a^{'3} \: mod \: p>> a'' @>a^{''3} \: mod \: p>>\\
    @VVa^5 \: mod \: pV @VVa^{'5} \: mod \: pV @VVa^{''5} \: mod \: pV\\
    A @>>A^3 \: mod \: p> A' @>>A^{'3} \: mod \: p> A'' @>>A^{''3} \: mod \: p>
\end{CD}

Comment: Look into the "DH Double Ratchet" algorithm.

Comment: Does everyone know what the "noise X pattern is"? Perhaps it requires an explanation if it is important to the question.